# ¿Cómo agregar 1 divisor contenedor cada 2 columnas en un loop de WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, grid

estoy armando un loop en WordPress, el cual tiene el siguiente aspecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código, el cual funciona bien pero no se donde introducir el div que solo se repita cada vez que aparecen las 2 columnas:

```
    $i = 0; 
    if (have_posts()): 
        while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $wide_t = get_field('wide_thumbnail');
            $size_w = 'thumb-works-wide';
            $thumb_wide = $wide_t['sizes'][ $size_w ];
            $width_w = $wide_t['sizes'][ $size_w . '-width' ];
            $height_w = $wide_t['sizes'][ $size_w . '-height' ];   
                if (get_field('formato') == 'Wide') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb-wide left permalink">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumb_wide; ?>" width="<?php echo $width_w; ?>" height="<?php echo $height_w; ?>" alt="">  
                    </a>
                <?php } ?> 
            <?php if($i % 2 == 0): 
                // vars
                $square_t = get_field('square_thumbnail');
                $size_s = 'thumb-works-square';
                $thumb_square = $square_t['sizes'][ $size_s ];
                $width_s = $square_t['sizes'][ $size_s . '-width' ];
                $height_s = $square_t['sizes'][ $size_s . '-height' ]; ?>
                    <?php if (get_field('formato') == 'Square') { ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb-square col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block permalink">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumb_square; ?>" width="<?php echo $width_s; ?>" height="<?php echo $height_s; ?>" alt="">    
                        </a>
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php endif;
        endwhile; 
    endif; $i++; ?>
```

Muchas gracias.